# Eligible variables for garbage collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, ocpjp

I am preparing for [OCPJP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Certification_Program), and I got stuck at the following mock exam question:

Given:

```
3. interface Animal { void makeNoise(); }

4. class Horse implements Animal {
5.     Long weight = 1200L;
6.     public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("whinny"); }
7. }

8. public class Icelandic extends Horse {
9.     public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("vinny"); }

10.    public static void main(String[] args) {
11.        Icelandic i1 = new Icelandic();
12.        Icelandic i2 = new Icelandic();
12.        Icelandic i3 = new Icelandic();
13.        i3 = i1; i1 = i2; i2 = null; i3 = i1;
14.    }
15. }
```

When line 14 is reached, how many objects are eligible for the garbage collector?

A. 0

B. 1

C. 2

D. 3

E. 4

F. 6

Their correct answer is E, i.e. four objects, but I'm not sure why. From my point of view, i2 and its weight will get eligible for garbage collection. Perhaps I'm missing something, please advise.

Comment: Their question is a little silly as garbage collection is irrelevant at program termination (at line 14)...

Comment: Just a clarification - are you sure that `weight` is a `Long` and not a `long` (object, not primitive)?

Comment: Wait...doesn't this entirely depend on how this program is called? Strings are objects, so any arguments provided would change the number of objects.

Comment: Those `String` are in the string constant pool, so they are not eligible for garbage collection (at least in the sense of the question).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure weight is Long, I made copy-paste for the entire code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets call `Icelandic()` on line 11 `IceA`, line 12 `IceB`, and so forth.

After creation

```
i1 = IceA
i2 = IceB
i3 = IceC
```

After `i3 = i1`

```
i1 = IceA
i2 = IceB
i3 = IceA
```

After `i1 = i2`

```
i1 = IceB
i2 = IceB
i3 = IceA
```

After `i2 = null`

```
i1 = IceB
i2 = null
i3 = IceA
```

After `i3 = i1`

```
i1 = IceB
i2 = null
i3 = IceB
```

So only the `Icelandic()` created on line 12 remains. Now, each `Icelandic()` has a `Long weight`, so `IceA` and `IceC` are now unreferenced, meaning 4 objects (`IceA`, `IceA.weight`, `IceC`, `IceC.weight`) are available for GC.

---

### Other issues:

1. `args` is still `args`, they are not counting going out of scope in this question
2. `Long weight` is not declared statically, so each instance of the class has a `weight` object.

Comment: And what about the weight(s)?

Comment: But on line 14, all of `i1`, `i2` and `i3` are out of scope, so `IceB` can also be GC'd, surely?

Comment: @DNA: That was my original answer, but then the answer would be 6. Clearly the question asker wants to know what's available for gc BEFORE things go out of scope.

Comment: Ah, the joys of badly-phrased exam questions ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the first Icelandic object that is created "A", the second one "B", and the third one "C". After line 12, they are referenced by i1, i2, and i3, respectively.

Now, we do:

```
i3 = i1; // object "C" is no longer referenced, object "A" is now referenced by i1 and i3
i1 = i2; // object "A" is just referenced by i3, object "B" is referenced by i1 and i2
i2 = null; // object "B" is just referenced by i1 now
i3 = i1; // object "B" is referenced by i1 and i3, object "A" is no longer referenced
```

So, objects "A" and "C" are no longer referenced, and they along with their "weight" are eligible for garbage collection, so four objects total.

Comment: But *all* of these references are out of scope, and therefore don't prevent GC of any of these objects

Comment: @DNA, I take "when line 14 is reached" to mean just prior to `main()` being exited. Apparently, that's what the writers of the question intended if the answer is 4.

Comment: @DNA: I agree with you, but I think the question asker is saying "BEFORE line 14", not "After variables go out of scope"

Comment: Ah, that would explain it - it changes the meaning of the question entirely and makes all the messing around on line 13 relevant (otherwise it's a rather cruel diversion in an exam question!)

Comment: Right, it would have been better for the question writer to insert an actual line of code (like `System.out.println()` or something similar) at line 14 instead of the closing brace.

Answer (score 2):

You will have 4 objects in the system, 3 `Icelandic` instances and 1 `Long` instance.

When you assign constant object to some variable, compiler uses kind of `private static final Long long1200 = Long.valueOf(1200L);` object that is shared by all `weight` instances.

Primitive type wrappers are immutable, so it is safe to do this optimization.

EDIT: probably I am wrong, because this would work this way if we referenced the same constant several times here, which is not the case

Comment: You are semi-correct: The compiler or the Long implementation *is* optimizing the instances for smaller numbers so that it's only one. For larger numbers no longer: http://ideone.com/nsQoHr

Comment: Sure, this is runtime optimization of `Long.valueOf()`, I thought compiler does constant optimization too, and that appeared to be wrong