# What happens when an object is dereferenced but its member object is still referenced?

Tags: java

```
class ClassA {
    ClassB mem1 = new ClassB();
    ClassB mem2 = new ClassB();
}

class ClassB {
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA obj1 = new ClassA();
        ClassB obj2 = obj1.mem1;

        obj1 = null;

        obj2 = null;
    }
}
```

In the above program, what happens after the line: `obj1 = null`?

Is **obj1** ready for garbage collection even though one of its member object is still being referenced?

Comment: They're not accessible anymore.

Comment: It becomes eligible for GC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eligible variables for garbage collection in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634766/eligible-variables-for-garbage-collection-in-java)

Comment: obj1 is ready for GC, but obj2 is kept alive by the second reference in main.

Comment: `obj1` can be GC'd - but `obj2 == mem1` cannot be GC'd. Java is just one big reference graph - you can lop off a slice of the graph, but nodes can be referenced elsewhere. You can think of it as weights hanging by references (strings) from the root node (the ceiling). When you `null` a reference, you snip the string. If no more strings are holding the weight up, then it falls to the floor (GC).

Comment: `mem1` & `mem2` is not being referenced from `obj1` anymore as they are not accessible through it

Comment: I assume that, by "dereferenced" you really mean "no longer referenced".  Be aware that "dereference" has the established meaning in programming of referring to the act of referencing the thing pointed to by a pointer -- removing a level of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

[Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

In this context, when `obj1 = null;` is processed there are no references to the object of type `ClassA` to which it points, and so it is eligable for garbage collection.  The `ClassB` object, `mem1` however still has a reference in the form of `obj2` and so is kept at least until the line `obj2 = null;` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

After `obj1` is no longer referenced, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. `mem1` still has a reference, so if java were to garbage-collect at this point, `obj1` and `mem2` it points too would be freed, but `mem1` would remain untouched as `obj2` still points to it.

Of course, after `obj2 = null`, it can also be collected.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 instances of classes: One of `ClassA` (I call it `classA_1`) and two of `ClassB` (`classB_1`, `classB_2`). Now look at all the reference paths that exist to those 3 instances.

Before `obj1 = null` it looks smth. like this:

```
classA_1 <- Sample.main.obj1
classB_1 <- classA_1.mem1 <- Sample.main.obj1
classB_1 <- Sample.main.obj2
classB_2 <- classA_1.mem2 <- Sample.main.obj1
```

After `obj1 = null` it looks like this, where `no ref.` means, it is eligible for garbage collection, because it has no reference pointing to it.

```
classA_1 <- no ref.
classB_1 <- classA_1.mem1 <- no ref.
classB_1 <- Sample.main.obj2
classB_2 <- classA_1.mem2 <- no ref.
```

The only path that remains is this: `classB_1 <- Sample.main.obj2`. There a no paths with valid references to objects `classB_2` and `classA_1`. So these objects can be collected.